# Python Azure SDK - Unable to download zip file

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-files

I am using the latest version of `Azure Storgae SDK` on `Python 3.5.2`.

I want to download a **zip file** from a blob on Azure storage cloud.

**My Code:**

```
self.azure_service= BlockBlobService(account_name = ACCOUNT_NAME,
                                     account_key = KEY)

with open(local_path, "wb+") as f:
     self.azure_service.get_blob_to_stream(blob_container,
                                           file_cloud_path,
                                           f)
```

**The Error:**

`AzureException: ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.,, error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check',))`

The error is probably coming from the requests package and i don't seem to have access for changing the headers or something like that.

What exactly is the problem and how can i fix it?

Comment: Can you check the properties of the blob especially content-encoding property value? If it is set as gzip, just update the blob properties by setting its value to an empty string.

Comment: Worked! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as summary,I tried to verify the above exception with Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer Tool.

When user upload a **zip** type file , if set the **EncodingType** property for **gzip**.

[image]

at the time of download the client will check whether the file type can be to depressed to **EncodingType** , if dismatch will occur the exception as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 266, in _decode
    data = self._decoder.decompress(data)
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 66, in decompress
    return self._obj.decompress(data)
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 745, in generate
    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 436, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 408, in read
    data = self._decode(data, decode_content, flush_decoder)
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 271, in _decode
    "failed to decode it." % content_encoding, e)
urllib3.exceptions.DecodeError: ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\storageclient.py", line 222, in _perform_request
    response = self._httpclient.perform_request(request)
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\_http\httpclient.py", line 114, in perform_request
    proxies=self.proxies)
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 658, in send
    r.content
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 823, in content
    self._content = bytes().join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or bytes()
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 750, in generate
    raise ContentDecodingError(e)
requests.exceptions.ContentDecodingError: ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PythonWorkSpace/AzureStorage/BlobStorage/CreateContainer.py", line 20, in <module>
    f)
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\baseblobservice.py", line 1932, in get_blob_to_stream
    _context=operation_context)
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blob\baseblobservice.py", line 1659, in _get_blob
    operation_context=_context)
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\storageclient.py", line 280, in _perform_request
    raise ex
  File "D:\Python35\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\storageclient.py", line 252, in _perform_request
    raise AzureException(ex.args[0])
azure.common.AzureException: ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check',))

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Solution:**

As @Gaurav Mantri sail, you could set the EncodingType property to **None** or ensure that the EncodingType setting matches the type of the file itself.

[image]

Also,you could refer to the SO thread  [python making POST request with JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24254361/python-making-post-request-with-json-data).